# Passing variables inside double quotes

Tags: vba

I am writing a `VBA`  code , where I need to pass few variables inside double quotes.
Code as below

```
Set newrel = rels.AddWithRoleName("Entity1", "Entity1", 1," attr1,attr1_role; col1, col1_role")
```

Here, for `"Entity1"` I can pass variables as there is only one values, but for the last parameters, `"attr1,attr1_role; col1, col1_role"`, I need to pass 4 variables for these parameters.

As this is inside double quotes, it is not taking the values when I am passing the variable names.

Comment: Hi @Arun, please see [ask] for some tips on improving your question. If you are passing variables, you should not encapsulate them in quotes like `"SomeVariable"` - this passes `SomeVariable` as a string, not the value of the variable. If you need to pass multiple values/variables within one argument/parameter, use the [concatenate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/concatenation-operator) operator (`&`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the following variables

- `attr1`
- `attr1_role`
- `col1`
- `col1_role`

and you want to pass them as a string like `"attr1,attr1_role; col1, col1_role"` then you need to make a concatenated string with your variables:

```
attr1 & "," & attr1_role & "; " & col1 & ", " & col1_role
```

For example:

```
Dim Parameter4 As String
Parameter4 = attr1 & "," & attr1_role & "; " & col1 & ", " & col1_role

Set newrel = rels.AddWithRoleName(Entity1, Entity1, 1, Parameter4)
```

*Make sure to use a more meaningful name than `Parameter4` in your production environment*.